# Using iBeacons for employees attendance

Tags: ibeacon, estimote

Is it possible to replace access cards and attendance checkin/out by installing iBeacons network? the main concern is how to know if the user is entering or existing the premise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  I have worked with a number of folks who have tried this.  But there are challenges:

- It only works for employees with Android and iOS phones that support BLE, have a company app, and have Bluetooth turned on.
- Phones that are turned off, in airplane mode, or have a dead battery will not detect.
- You must either have full coverage of the office using BLE beacon signals (requiring lots of beacons) or rely on beacons at entry/exit points.  If you rely on entry/exit points you never know for sure if employees are coming or going.
- You need a web app to receive detections and show the attendance reports.
- Employee phones must have data connectivity to send the detections to the server.  If there is bad coverage on site, this will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please elaborate more on how to figure the user movement direction, in or out?